# Why synchronization is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

problem here is synchronization is not working. My other thread gets executed even before my first thread has finished its execution in synchronized block. When I'm passing "someClass.class", then it works fine. Maybe my understading is wrong or maybe my program has some fault.

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedObject object = new SharedObject();
        ClassA t1 = new ClassA("Thread 1", object);
        ClassA t2 = new ClassA("Thread 2", object);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

SharedObject:

```
class SharedObject {
    volatile int value = 10;
}
```

ClassA:

```
class ClassA extends Thread{
    SharedObject object;
    int data;

    public ClassA(String name, SharedObject object) {
        super(name);
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        name();
    }

    public void name() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if(getName().equals("Thread 1")){
                System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
                object.value = 100;
                System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
                data = object.value;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
                object.value = 200;
                System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
                data = object.value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Before modifying Thread 2 value = 10
Before modifying Thread 1 value = 10
After modifying Thread 2 value = 200
After modifying Thread 1 value = 100
```

Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Do you know what `synchronized(this)` means?

Comment: This problem is also seen when I'm synchronizing method.

Comment: lock will be taken on current object @user3580294

Comment: And you have two different "current objects", right?

Comment: You created a sharedObject which both threads have access to, but rather than locking on it you lock on different objects.  Perhaps synchronization is not working as you are not using it correctly ;)

Comment: I suggest you print `System.out.println("this= "+this);` and you will see you have two "this" objects.

Comment: Thanks All, I'm not sure why I passed this in synchronized block. I passed the common object for this puprpose but didn't used it.

Answer (score 5):

You are synchronizing on "this", but have created 2 different instances of ClassA. So the synchronization takes place on different objects.

Comment: Thanks Brett, got the issue.

Answer (score 3):

While most answers are correct, let me add some more explanations on the different types of synchronization you can do.

#### Synchronized method

For example:

```
public synchronized void name() {
    
        if(getName().equals("Thread 1")){
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 100;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 200;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }
}
```

This makes sure that **only one** thread will execute this **specific** method at one point in time for that particular **instance**. Any other thread will wait at the method starting point.

#### Synchronized instance

For example:

```
public void name() {

    synchronized (this) {
        if(getName().equals("Thread 1")){
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 100;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 200;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }
    }

}
```

This makes sure that **only one** thread will execute this **specific** block at one point in time for that particular **instance**. Any other thread will wait at the beginning of the block.

When the synchronized block encompasses the whole method, this is equivalent to the synchronized method.

#### Synchronized class

```
public void name() {

    synchronized (ClassA.class) {
        if(getName().equals("Thread 1")){
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 100;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 200;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }
    }

}
```

This makes sure that **only one** thread will execute this **specific** block at one point in time for **any instances** of the class. Any other thread will wait at the beginning of the block. This is a possible fix to your problem.

#### Synchronizing mutex

While all above methods use an implicit mutex, a good way of synchronizing threads is to use your own mutex. This improves overall extensibility if you go deeper into concurrency implementations.

For example:

```
private staic final Object mutex = new Object();

public void name() {

    synchronized (mutex) {
        if(getName().equals("Thread 1")){
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 100;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Before modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            object.value = 200;
            System.out.println("After modifying "+getName()+" value = "+object.value);
            data = object.value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything you say is true, but it could be simplified by decomposing the explanation into two parts:  First, explain what a synchronized(foo) {...} block does, and then explain how to re-write synchronized static methods and synchronized instance methods using the explicit synchronized(foo) {...} syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to synchronize on `object` and not on `this`.

`this` is different for `t1` and `t2` because they are two different instances of the same class, hence the concurrent execution.

Comment: Thanks @Vakh, god knows what i was thinking while writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize on the shared object (referenced by variable named `object`) not on the Thread instance (referenced by `this`).